# Get notified when the submitted POST request finishes (if the response is not HTML)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, form-submit

In the master page of all my web form pages I've set up an overlay which blocks user interation whenever form submitted until browser renders next page response:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function overlayWhenSubmit() {
    document.getElementById('spinnerOverlay').style.display = 'block';
  }
  //spinnerOverlay has position:fixed and top/bottom/left/right:0
</script>
```

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e) {
  this.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(
    typeof(Page), null, "overlayWhenSubmit();"
  );
  base.OnPreRender(e);
}
```

This works great until I try to provide file download:

```
public static void DownloadFile(this System.Web.HttpResponse @this, string physicalFilePath) {
  @this.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
  @this.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", $"Attachment; filename=\"{Path.GetFileName(physicalFilePath)}\"");
  @this.TransmitFile(physicalFilePath);
}
// ... then in some event handler in my page:
Response.DownloadFile(thePathOfFileToDownload);
```

The file downloads OK, but the original page keeps being overlaid and therefore unusable.

Is there a way the page can get notified when the submitted request has finished so it can turn off the overlay?

Comment: Yes the overlay will be there because the page is not refreshed since a file is send to the client, not a html page. You have to change `overlayWhenSubmit()` so it does not trigger when downloading a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing so far is try not to popup the overlay for the control which leads to non-HTML response:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function overlayWhenSubmit() {
  if (!document.getElementById('noOverlayWhenSubmit').value)
    document.getElementById('spinnerOverlay').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('noOverlayWhenSubmit').value = '';
}
function noOverlayWhenSubmit() {
  document.getElementById('noOverlayWhenSubmit').value = true;
}
</script>

<input type="hidden" id="noOverlayWhenSubmit" value="" />

<asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick="noOverlayWhenSubmit()"></asp:Button>
```